# Javascript fetch, catch runs forever

Tags: javascript, try-catch, fetch

**What happens:** If I use fetch..catch and calls another function. In that next function if anything crashes. It will be caught in last catch. This will go on so if the next function crashes it will still be caught in the fetch..catch

**What I want:** When calling myExternalFunction() I want to 'disconnect' from the try..catch that fetch throws.

```
fetch('mystuff.url')
   .then((data)=>{
      myExternalFunction();
   })
   .catch((e)=>{
      // all future errors will come here
   })

myExternalFunction(){
    // This error will be caught by fetch..catch 
    // we don't want that
    crash();
}
```

[Fiddler example to try it](https://jsfiddle.net/fbacker/ayq0w01o/1/)

Comment: add a try/catch in myExternalFunction

Comment: @Kulvar: That is an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to *chain* your `catch` to the `then` then, but keep them at the same level:

```
fetch(...).then(successCallback, failCallback)
```

Or:

```
const p = fetch(...);
p.then(successCallback);
p.catch(failCallback);
```

```js
const p = Promise.resolve('foo');
p.then(() => { throw new Error('noooooo') });
p.catch(() => console.error('caught'));
```

The difference is that `fetch().then().catch()` will `catch` any error produced by either the `fetch` promise or the `then` promise; while the above two methods apply the `failCallback` only to the `fetch` promise.

Comment: The first example works. But as long as you add .catch to the fetch its the same issue. So basically never use catch with fetch. Use the success/fail callback in then.

Comment: @roady I've added an executable code snippet: exceptions thrown in `successCallback` are *not* caught by `p.catch`!

Comment: So you shouldn't use catch with fetch. If you want to. Check  my suggestion with setTimeout(myExternalFunction,1);

Comment: Err, no, you simply *don’t chain `catch`* to the function producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

> When calling myExternalFunction() I want to 'disconnect' from the
>   try..catch that fetch throws.

**Catch the exception of `crash` in `myExternalFunction` itself.**

```
fetch('mystuff.url')
   .then((data)=>{
      myExternalFunction();
   })
   .catch((e)=>{
      // all future errors will come here
   })

function myExternalFunction(){
    try
    { 
       crash(); 
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      //do nothing 
    }
}
```

**Or (*if modifying external function is not possible*) `catch` the same in `then`**

```
fetch('mystuff.url')
   .then((data)=>{
      try
      { 
         myExternalFunction();
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        //do nothing 
      }
   })
   .catch((e)=>{
      // all future errors will come here
   })

function myExternalFunction(){
    crash(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't want to wrap the 'external function' in try..catch (then we need to continue to wrap next call as well and so on. This issue can be noted when e.g. using react with redux thunk. How a fetch..catch captures errors happening somewhere else.

To completly break we need something else as setTimeout. Must be a better way for this.

```
fetch('mystuff.url')
   .then((data)=>{
      // this will break out so 'external function' doesn't get caught in catch.
      setTimeout(myExternalFunction,1);
   })
   .catch((e)=>{
      // only errors from the fetch
   })

function myExternalFunction(){
    crash(); // we are happy, it crashes without involving fetch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *catch* with *fetch* I propose to use this solution.

```js
fetch("http://httpstat.us/500")
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.status);
        }
        return response;
    }).then(function(response) {
        alert("ok");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });
```